# Why is the following sentence ungrammatical?

Tags: syntax, semantics

"The man entertained by the doves his sandwich munched."

Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: It sounds grammatical to me, but because it reads like a verse of poetry, where SOV order is kosher.  MSE uses SVO, and so in prose it's not correct because "his sandwich" needs to come after "munched".

Answer (score 2):

The man munched his sandwich.

- SVO order is pretty critical in English unless you are writing poetry, as

The man (, who was) entertained by the doves.

- missing link words...

SO finally

The man (, who was) entertained by the doves, munched his sandwich.